# Group nodes by child & parent taxonomy with Views - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have one content type with one taxonomy field with parent->child terms. In one view I need to group nodes by the child selected but also by the parent.

**Expected output**

> - parent 1 <- taxonomy parent
>
>   - term 1 <- taxonomy child
>
>     - title 1 <- node
>     - title 2
>     - title 3
>   - term 2
>
>     - title 4
>     - title 5
> - parent 2
>
>   - term 3
>
>     - title 6
>     - title 7
>   - term 4
>
>     - title 8
>     - title 9

**Current output**

> - parent 1
>
>   - term 1 & title 1
>   - term 1 & title 2
>   - term 1 & title 3
>   - term 2 & title 4
>   - term 2 & title 5
> - parent 2
>
>   - term 3 & title 6
>   - term 3 & title 7
>   - term 4 & title 8
>   - term 4 & title 9

**Current view config**

> - Relationships
>
>   - Taxonomy terms on node <- child
>   - Term taxonomy <- parent
> - Format
>
>   - Unformatted list
>   - Grouping field: parent
> - Fields
>
>   - Taxonomy term <- parent
>   - Exclude from display
>   - Taxonomy term <- child
>   - Content title <- node
> - Filter
>
>   - Content type (= My content Type)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got it! Solution

**Node view**

> - View machine name: node_view_machine_name
> - Type: Block
> - Fields
>
>   - Title
>   - Field 1
>   - Field 2
> - Filter
>
>   - Content type (= My content Type)
> - Contextual filters
>
>   - Child taxonomy field
>   - Hide view when filter is not available

**Taxonomy view**

> - Type: page
> - Filter
>
>   - Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (= My Vocabulary)
> - Relationship
>
>   - Taxonomy term: Parent term
> - Fields
>
>   - Taxonomy term: Name
>
>     - Relationship: parent
>     - Exclude from display
>   - Taxonomy term: ID <- We use this id to pass as argument to the node view
>
>     - Relationship: none
>     - Exclude from display
>   - Taxonomy term: Name
>
>     - Relationship: none
>   - Global PHP <- Print node detail related for each child term
>
>     - Output code:

```
$viewNodeDetail = views_get_view('node_view_machine_name');
$viewNodeDetail ->set_arguments(array($row->tid));
print $viewNodeDetail ->render('block');
```

> - Format
>
>   - Group by
>   - (Parent) Taxonomy term: Name

I hope can be useful for someone else!

Comment: This helped me thanks. 2 things I had to do differently:  1. Taxonomy View - Relationship needed "Require this relationship" ticked            and 2. Taxonomy View - instead of Taxonomy Term: Name I had to use Taxonomy Term: Rendered Taxonomy Term

Comment: Another solution is to use views_field_view then you don't have to mess around with custom php